# How to change this class to download audio file?

Tags: android

I have this class that downloads an image from a server and that I carry it on my main activity

```
    public class imgDownloader extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {

    private ProgressBar pb;
    private String url;
    private Button save;
    private Context c;
    private int progress;
    private ImageView img;
    private Bitmap bmp;
    private TextView percent;
    private ImageLoaderListener listener;


    /*--- constructor ---*/
    public ImageDownloader(String url, ProgressBar pb, Button save,
            ImageView img, TextView percent, Context c, Bitmap bmp, ImageLoaderListener listener) {
    /*--- we need to pass some objects we are going to work with ---*/
        this.url = url;
        this.pb = pb;
        this.save = save;
        this.c = c;
        this.img = img;
        this.percent = percent;
        this.bmp = bmp;
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    /*--- we need this interface for keeping the reference to our Bitmap from the MainActivity. 
     *  Otherwise, bmp would be null in our MainActivity*/
    public interface ImageLoaderListener {

        void onImageDownloaded(Bitmap bmp);

        }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        //progress = 0;
        //pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        //percent.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        //Toast.makeText(c, "starting download", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d("Script", "//" + "starting download");
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

        bmp = getBitmapFromURL(url);
/*
        while (progress < 10) {

            progress += 1;

            publishProgress(progress);


          SystemClock.sleep(200);

        }
*/
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {

    /*--- show download progress on main UI thread---*/
    //  pb.setProgress(values[0]);
    //  percent.setText(values[0] + "%");

        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        if (listener != null) {
            listener.onImageDownloaded(bmp);
            }
        img.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        //save.setEnabled(true);
        //Toast.makeText(c, "download complete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d("Script", "//" + "download complete");
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }


    }
```

**I need instead of downloading an image to download a mp3 audio file and use the call of my NOTIFICATION**

This is where I use some flags and use an audio that is in my raw pasta.

```
noti.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://"
 + _context.getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.galo);
noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
noti.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONLY_ALERT_ONCE;
noti.priority = Notification.PRIORITY_MAX;
mNotificationManager.notify(MESSAGE_NOTIFICATION_ID, noti);
```

Here I need to use the same class adapted upon to download the audio, but do not know how I can do this. Download the audio file and let the SDCARD is out of the question.

```
  noti.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + _context.getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.galo);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this class to download file

//to call
new DownloadFileFromURL().execute("download_url");

//Class to download file

```
class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> 
 {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread
         * Show Progress Bar Dialog
         * */

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            super.onPreExecute();

            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            pDialog.setMessage("Downloading file. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setMax(100);
            pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }
        /**
         * Downloading file in background thread
         * */
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... f_url)
        {
            int count;
            try
            {


                //file name with extension
                File file=new File("/directory/file.mp3");

                URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);
                URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
                conection.connect();
                // this will be useful so that you can show a tipical 0-100% progress bar
                int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();

                // download the file
                InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);

                // Output stream
                OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file);

                byte data[] = new byte[1024];

                long total = 0;

                while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                    total += count;
                    // publishing the progress....
                    // After this onProgressUpdate will be called
                    publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));

                    // writing data to file
                    output.write(data, 0, count);
                }

                // flushing output
                output.flush();

                // closing streams
                output.close();
                input.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * Updating progress bar
         * */
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
            // setting progress percentage
            pDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task
         * Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after the file was downloaded
            pDialog.dismiss();

        }

    }
```

Comment: Hello friend, this low class local file saved to the sdcard.
Would you like a class and return to download the audio file to be able to use the notification.